# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate the activity

Tags: java, android

i starting make a game project for android, i have make 2 activity (mainactivity and Pvsp) and then all activity that i described before, i have add at the manifest. but the logcat give me error like this

```
11-08 15:50:10.339: E/Trace(6221): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-08 15:50:10.339: V/ActivityThread(6221): com.rhas.skripsiletsgo white listed for hwui
11-08 15:50:14.339: D/dalvikvm(6221): newInstance failed: no <init>()
11-08 15:50:14.349: D/AndroidRuntime(6221): Shutting down VM
11-08 15:50:14.359: W/dalvikvm(6221): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a8e930)
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.rhas.skripsiletsgo/com.rhas.skripsiletsgo.Pvsp}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.rhas.skripsiletsgo.Pvsp; no empty constructor
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2223)
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5259)
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.rhas.skripsiletsgo.Pvsp; no empty constructor
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2214)
11-08 15:50:14.389: E/AndroidRuntime(6221):     ... 11 more
11-08 15:50:16.099: I/Process(6221): Sending signal. PID: 6221 SIG: 9
```

then here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rhas.skripsiletsgo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.rhas.skripsiletsgo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name="com.rhas.skripsiletsgo.Pvsp"
            android:label="@string/app_name">           
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

here is my [Project](http://www.mediafire.com/download/2b87ql9k42792dz/SkripsiLetsGo.zip), feel free for editing, analysis, etc. sorry for my bad english.
all help/comments are appreciated.

**EDIT :** here is the Pvsp class

```
package com.rhas.skripsiletsgo;

import static com.rhas.skripsiletsgo.core.StoneColor.BLACK;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import com.rhas.skripsiletsgo.StoneDrawable;
import com.rhas.skripsiletsgo.core.KoRuleException;
import com.rhas.skripsiletsgo.core.NoLibertiesException;
import com.rhas.skripsiletsgo.core.SpaceTakenException;
import com.rhas.skripsiletsgo.core.Game;
import com.rhas.skripsiletsgo.core.GameState;
import com.rhas.skripsiletsgo.core.Stone;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Pvsp extends ViewGroup{

    public Pvsp(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setKeepScreenOn(true);

        stones = new Stone[game.getTableSize()][game.getTableSize()];
        blackStoneDrawable = new StoneDrawable.Black();
        whiteStoneDrawable = new StoneDrawable.White();
        gridDrawable = new GridDrawable(game.getTableSize());

        setGameState(game.getLastState());
        game.addListener(new GameListener());
    }

    static final int MAX_DRAWN_CAPTURED_STONES = 16;

    final static int PADDING = 3;

    final GridDrawable gridDrawable;

    final Rect rect = new Rect();

    final Stone[][] stones;
    StoneDrawable blackStoneDrawable;
    StoneDrawable whiteStoneDrawable;

    long lastTouchMove = -1;

    Game game;

    GameState gameState;

    int cellSize;

    private boolean skipNextTouchUp;

    void setGameState(GameState state){
        if(gameState != null){
            Set<Stone> prevStones = gameState.getStones();
            Set<Stone> newStones = state.getStones();
            Set<Stone> prevStonesM = new HashSet<Stone>(prevStones);
            Set<Stone> newStonesM = new HashSet<Stone>(newStones);

            prevStonesM.removeAll(newStones);
            for(Stone stone : prevStonesM){
                stones[stone.getRow()][stone.getCol()] = null;
            }

            newStonesM.removeAll(prevStones);
            for(Stone stone : newStonesM){
                stones[stone.getRow()][stone.getCol()] = stone;
            }
            invalidate();
        }
        gameState = state;
    }

    private int getX(int row){
        int l = rect.left + cellSize / 2 + PADDING;
        int r = rect.right - cellSize / 2 - PADDING;
        return getCoord(row, l, r);
    }

    private int getY(int col){
        int t = rect.top + cellSize / 2 + PADDING;
        int b = rect.bottom + cellSize / 2 - PADDING;
        return getCoord(col, t, b);
    }

    private int getCoord(int i, int min, int max){
        return min + (max - min) * i / (game.getTableSize() - 1);
    }

    private int getRow(float y){
        return Math.round(0.5f + (y - PADDING) / (rect.bottom - rect.top - 2*PADDING) * game.getTableSize() - 1);
    }

    private int getCol(float x){
        return Math.round(0.5f + (x - PADDING) / (rect.right - rect.left - 2*PADDING) * game.getTableSize() - 1);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        int p = PADDING + cellSize / 2;
        canvas.clipRect(p, p, rect.width() - p, rect.height() - p);
        gridDrawable.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        drawStones(canvas);
        drawCapturedStones(canvas);
        drawWhoseTurn(canvas);
    }

    private void drawStones(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i = 0; i < stones.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < stones[i].length; j++){
                Stone stone = stones[i][j];
                if(stone == null) continue;
                int x = getX(stone.getCol());
                int y = getY(stone.getRow());
                canvas.save();
                canvas.translate(x - cellSize / 2, y - cellSize / 2);
                if(stone.getColor() == BLACK){
                    blackStoneDrawable.draw(canvas);
                }else{
                    whiteStoneDrawable.draw(canvas);
                }
                canvas.restore();
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawCapturedStones(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int dx = PADDING + cellSize / 2;
        int dy = rect.height() + cellSize;

        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(dx, dy);
        drawCapturedStones(canvas, gameState.getBlacksCaptured(), blackStoneDrawable, false);
        canvas.restore();

        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(canvas.getWidth() - dx - cellSize, dy);
        drawCapturedStones(canvas, gameState.getWhitesCaptured(), whiteStoneDrawable, true);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private void drawCapturedStones(Canvas canvas, int count, StoneDrawable drawable, boolean flip){
        if(count > MAX_DRAWN_CAPTURED_STONES){
            count = MAX_DRAWN_CAPTURED_STONES;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            int rowCol = Util.getCapturedRowCol(i);
            int row = (rowCol / 1000);
            int col = rowCol % 1000;

            if(flip){
                col = -col;
            }

            canvas.save();
            int x = col * cellSize;
            int y = row * cellSize;
            canvas.translate(x, y);
            drawable.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }

    private void drawWhoseTurn(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int dx = 5 * cellSize + cellSize / 2 + PADDING;
        int dy = rect.height();
        canvas.save();
        StoneDrawable drawable;
        if (gameState.getWhoseTurn() == BLACK) {
          // Flip horizontally.
          canvas.translate(rect.width() - dx - 2 * cellSize, dy);
          drawable = blackStoneDrawable;
        } else {
          canvas.translate(dx, dy);
          drawable = whiteStoneDrawable;
        }
        int oldSize = drawable.getSize();
        drawable.setSize(2 * cellSize);
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        drawable.setSize(oldSize);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!changed) return;
        rect.left = l;
        rect.top = t;
        rect.right = Math.min(r, b);
        rect.bottom = Math.min(r, b);

        cellSize = (rect.width() - 2 * PADDING) / game.getTableSize();
        blackStoneDrawable.setSize(cellSize);
        whiteStoneDrawable.setSize(cellSize);
    }

    void skipNextTouchUp() {
        this.skipNextTouchUp = true;
    }

    class PlaceStoneTimer extends Timer {
    }

    PlaceStoneTimer placeStoneTimer = new PlaceStoneTimer();

    class PlaceStoneTimerTask extends TimerTask {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        gridDrawable.highlight();
        postInvalidate();
      }
    }

    @Override
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int row = getRow(event.getY());
        int col = getCol(event.getX());
        gridDrawable.unhighlight();
        invalidate();
        if (row < 0 || row >= game.getTableSize() || col < 0 || col >= game.getTableSize()) {
          return true;
        }
        switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (gridDrawable.getHighlightedRow() == null) {
              gridDrawable.prehighlight(row, col);
              placeStoneTimer.schedule(new PlaceStoneTimerTask(), 50000);
            } else if (gridDrawable.getHighlightedRow() != row
                || gridDrawable.getHighlightedCol() != col) {
              gridDrawable.prehighlight(row, col);
              placeStoneTimer.cancel();
              placeStoneTimer.schedule(new PlaceStoneTimerTask(), 50000);
            }
            return true;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (skipNextTouchUp) {
              skipNextTouchUp = false;
              return true;
            }
            try {
              game.makeTurnAt(row, col);
            } catch (SpaceTakenException e) {
              // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "This space is taken",
              // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (NoLibertiesException e) {
              Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No liberty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (KoRuleException e) {
              String msg = "Ko rule violation";
              if (e.getTurnsAgo() > 2) {
                msg = "Super ko rule violation " + e.getTurnsAgo() + " turns ago";
              }
              Toast.makeText(getContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        return true;
      }

    private class GameListener implements com.rhas.skripsiletsgo.core.GameListener {

        public void onStateAdvanced(GameState newState) {
          setGameState(newState);
        }

        public void onGameReset() {
          for (int row = 0; row < game.getTableSize(); row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < game.getTableSize(); col++) {
              stones[row][col] = null;
            }
          }
          removeAllViews();
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: can you post the Pvsp class here

Comment: i have edited the thread, check it sir

Comment: where you are instantiating this Pvsp and how?

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because your Pvsp class is not an activity class. you made the Pvsp class a custom layout so now what you have to do is to make this code run is:--

1.Make activity Pvsp and set your custom layout pvsp.
 eg.

```
class PvspActivity extends Activity{
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
setContentView(new Pvsp());
}

}
```

and also dont forget to add this activity in manifest:--

```
<activity 
        android:name="com.rhas.skripsiletsgo.PvspActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">           
    </activity>
```

and remove the pvsp as activity in manifest because it is not activity.let me know if any issue arise.thanks

Comment: is that possible to change the onCreate to Protected Void ? is that no problem ? and im still got error in setContentView like this. http://imageshack.us/f/196/zfrm.png/

Comment: nope you cant... and if setcontentview has problem then may be your layout has problem just check it

Comment: so, i must follow your instruction without change anything ? (except about the manifest)

Comment: ok, for the layout is done. but onCreate got "X" Sign like this http://imageshack.us/f/706/r9iz.png/

Comment: just try to use the content assistance provided by eclipse then it will not come..

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
<activity 
        android:name="com.rhas.skripsiletsgo.Pvsp"
        android:label="@string/app_name">           
</activity>
```

from your manifest. Pvsp isn't an activity